# Simple Rails SQL error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Im getting the following error when attempting to build a list of 'interests' check boxes in my form (models also listed below)... Any ideas? Thanks!

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in User_steps#show

Showing /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal/app/views/user_steps/show.html.erb where line #19 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: person_interests.interest_id: SELECT "interests".* FROM "interests" INNER JOIN "person_interests" ON "interests"."id" = "person_interests"."interest_id" WHERE "person_interests"."person_id" = 11 AND "person_interests"."person_type" = 'User'
Extracted source (around line #19):

16:   <legend>Interests & Holidays</legend>
17:   <h4>Select your top 3 interests..</h4>
18: 
19: <%= f.simple_fields_for :interests do |interest_f| %>
20:   <%= interest_f.input :interest, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false %>
21:    <% end %>
22:   <br></br>



class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,     :interests_attributes, :city, :zipcode, :date_of_birth, :gender, :address, :interest_ids, :holiday_ids, :friends_attributes, :person_interest_ids, :friends
  has_many :friends
  has_many :person_interests, :as => :person
  has_many :interests, :through => :person_interests

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :friends,  allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :interests, allow_destroy: true

end

class PersonInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :person_id, :person_type
  belongs_to :interest
  belongs_to :person, :polymorphic => true
end


class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :person_interests
  has_many :people, :through => :person_interests
end
```

Comment: I may not know a darn thing about rails, but based on the error you're getting, it sounds to me like your `person_interests` table doesn't have a column named `interest_id`.

Comment: Are you up to date on your migrations?

Comment: yes, @Travesty3 was right, i needed an interest_id column.. the forms are now appearing but not saving to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this error message:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: person_interests.interest_id

It appears that your `person_interests` table does not have a column named `interest_id`.